# Unrecognized error occured in the Windows Web Services framework

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, .net-core

After installing Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, Visual Studio Tools and .NET Core SDK on Windows 10, Creating new application: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/index   I can easily run this application in Command Line, but can not debug in Visual Studio:

[image]

The same is true for ASP.NET core. No antivirus run on the PC and all old MVC, console applications could be easily debugged. The problem is specific to .NET core applications only

Comment: .NET Core apps are not in *.exe but *.dll. You will have to check if the configuration is wrong.

Comment: In my case I changed to a new user profile on my Windows 10 station, other than Administrator user, under which all installations (VS, Tools, SDK....) have been performed. And debug for all kind of .net Core applications is working with Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. I will continue investigate the case, as two issues are obvious: 1. The problem is definitely with some settings, stored by development environment in user profile. 2. The problem is related to Tools, as debug worked before I installed the Tools to have .net core templates, and Tools I had to install with param: SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1

Comment: Lex, you can easily create .net exe application, like console application or self hosted web application as described in manuals

Comment: If other user profile has no this issue, one possible reason is that your current user has the visit account issue. How about opening the VS as the admin? If you move your project to a another new shared folder, how about the result?